# join two tables that have no foriegn keys in each other via a third table

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say that I have three tables: A,B and C.

I want to join A and C but there is no foriegn key from A to C or from C to A, but B has foriegn keys from both of them !

I want to update a line in A but in Condition that depends on the values on a record in C !!
I hope i'm making this clear enough, sorry for my bad english . Thank you in advance !!

Comment: You might want to clarify your problem with examples, though personally I do not believe you have researched this enough yourself. Look into how JOINS are used in SQL as this is quite a basic problem that a quick search would solve.

Comment: Ok, so B is implementing a many-to-many relationship between A and C. That is clear. But what you want to do is not... please explain what you want... what you tried... what errors you are getting.

Comment: I really have no idea how to explain it anymore :/

Comment: This is a very common situation actually.Please provide the table structures of A, B , C and the relation(foreign keys) between them

Comment: `but in Condition that can only be viewed in C` what does that mean

Comment: A(titre(30), nature(20), responsable(20))
C(nom(30), couleur(10), volume(double), ratelier(int), camion(int))
B(titre(30), utilisateur(20), accessoire(30))

the "titre" in B is a fk of "titre" in A
and "accessoire" in B is a fk of "nom" in C

so i want to edit the "responsable" column in A if he is using an accessoire that has a volume > 0.3

so here is it

Comment: You can join the three table as described in the various answers below.  However - foreign key relationships between tables are not random!  Each encodes one very specific bit of information about your business.  Be very, very certain that your table "B" has a meaning suitable for your current purpose.  Otherwise your results will be senseless junk.

Comment: @MichaelGreen the result was i exactly what i wanted. so that makes anything but senseless junk.

Comment: Good. I'm genuinely glad you got your question answered.  Be aware it only works because table B encodes the meaning "A *is using* Accessoire C" and that is what you are looking for.  If it had encoded the meaning "A *manufactures* Accessoire C" or "A *sells* Accessoire C" it would have been useless for your purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your question is particularly clear, but if I understand correctly you want to update table A depending on constraints in table C. Something along the lines of the following would work:

```
UPDATE
    a
SET
    columnName = 'newValue'
FROM
    a
    INNER JOIN b ON a.columnA = b.columnA
    INNER JOIN c ON c.columnC = b.columnC
WHERE
    c.columnName = 'condition'
```

You might also find the following question useful:

- [How do I UPDATE from a SELECT in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334712/update-from-select-using-sql-server)

Comment: OMG it worked . thank you very much, you're genius enough to undestand why i was trying to say . thanks a lot

Comment: You might want to flag an answer then which will help others identify that you've already solved your problem :-)